# Play .mp3 or .gif file in Google AppMaker

Tags: javascript, mp3, google-app-maker

Is there a way we can play **audio** sound or **Gif** image on Google AppMaker? I have tried the following to play **.sound** that I kept as HTML containing the .mp3 file src I copied from the Resources.

```
var page = app.pages.RateToilet;
var x = page.descendants.sound;

function playAudio() {
      x.play();
}
```

I got the following error

```
x.play is not a function
at playAudio (client:24:7)
at RateToilet.Image7.onClick:5:3
```

Please advise .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To play a **.gif** file is pretty straight forward. After you've uploaded the file to the resources section of appmaker, you simply need to drag and drop as shown below.

[image]

Now, to play a sound you've saved inside the resources, please do the following:

1) Add a button widget and set its text property to "play sound". 
 2) Add the following code to the **onClick** event of the button widget:

```
var track = "";
var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
audio.setAttribute("src", track);
if(widget.text === "play sound") {
  widget.text = "stop sound";
  audio.play();
} else {
  widget.text = "play sound";  
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
}
```

3) Add an HTML widget below the button widget. 
4) Make sure to check the **allowUnsafeHtml** checkbox 
5) Put the following inside the HTML widget html value:

```
<audio id="audio"></audio>
```

6) Next, go to the html display section and make sure to uncheck **visible** and set **visibility type** to hidden, just as shown below

[image]

7) Finally, go to the resources section of appmaker, copy the resource URL and paste its value inside the **onClick** event of the button widget, so that `var track` equals to that value. See below:

[image]

I built this little demo app for you hoping it could help you.
You can download from **[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1SDu2I72HuFmlMOZCfMOsn7cTPvAovOUW/view?usp=sharing)**. I hope it helps!

Comment: hey thanks a lot! but for the audio .. how if it is place in the resources? how to link it? how to get the audio link like you did?

Comment: @MuhammadAlifBinAzali- I see what you mean. I have updated the answer to match your needs. That is all I can do for you. Hope it helps you.